# i accidently change my root privilege, how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, xampp

so i accidently change my privilege of my root user and i cant do nothing right now the database is hidden cause dont have global privilege,

already try to change some line in the [mysqld] and add

`skip-grant-tables`

in my.ini but its cant change the privilage again bac to normal just say

`ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`

any solution of my problem ?

Comment: what statement can't be executed?

Comment: its all statement cause the root@localhost dont have any privilege  https://ibb.co/3S2Vz6r

Comment: so you need to run the database with `--skip-grant-tables` and add these... when do you get an error `ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MariaDB server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement` ?

Comment: yes its in xampp how do i change that grant to all again ?

Comment: check my answer, and accept it if it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini` (MySQL config file)

Find the line [mysqld] and right below it add skip-grant-tables. Example:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
port= 3306
socket = "C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir = "C:/xampp/mysql" 
tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp" 
[...etc...]
```

This should allow you to access MySQL if you don't know your password.

Stop and start MySQL from XAMPP to make this change take effect.

Next, in command line, connect to MySQL:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql.exe --user=root
```

Then run these commands:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Grant_priv='Y', Super_priv='Y' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
exit
```

Bring back your `my.ini` to normal by removing `skip-grant-tables`, restart the mysql server.

Done.

Comment: is this no problem ? or should be change ? https://ibb.co/bvnHjrr 

the grant is not updateable and i ty to change or create other user is the same https://ibb.co/nbCKyhJ

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: did you follow my steps? you should do it on command line, not PHPMyAdmin

Comment: i do in command line check the first link that prove i do it in commandline

Comment: and did you add `skip-grant-tables` to ini file and restart the database before?

Comment: yes already add and comment it after change and restart the database, but that message is Grant_priv is not updatable is the problem, can that field forced to update ?

Comment: I don't know... sorry :(

Comment: oke thats no problem ill search it later, hope somebody can help Thanks its form to make it normal but nor for the grant, btw i need 15 rep up vote ur post lol

Comment: what I can think of is to just make a dump of databases with `mysqldump -u[yourusername] -p[yourpassword] --all-databases > mydump.sql` command line, reinstall everything and then bring the data back with `mysql -u[yourusername] -p[yourpassword] < mydump.sql`

Comment: Man! U r my hero!  o/